# run maven project with eclipse

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, fedora

I'm new to `maven` and `eclipse`. I added `m2e-plugin` in `eclipse` and I imported an example of a maven project that I've found in the net. 
My problem is when I try to run the project in `eclipse` using the `Run as` item menu, I don't find the `maven package` menu as I learned in the different tutorials.

Is it a problem of installation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets go through this step by step to make sure you have everything you need to get going.

First of all make sure that you have Maven installed (and lets assume you have Java already). You can download it from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and installation instructions for Fedora (which I assume is what you are using from your tag) are further down the page.

To test that Maven is correctly installed and working type `mvn --help` in to the terminal. Eclipse and m2e pretty much just hop on to the terminal for everything Maven related so make sure this is working before proceeding.

Next download an appropriate version of Eclipse. For the sake of this example I've downloaded the Kepler version of the Java EE IDE. In this version of Eclipse m2e comes bundled and to check this you can go to `Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details` and on the plug-ins tab you should see the m2e connectors.

Now you can import your Maven project in to Eclipse. To do this go to `File > Import` and then choose *Existing Maven Projects* under the *Maven* section. Choose the directory with the example project that you've downloaded and then Finish.

Now, ensure that you have some file inside your example Maven project opened and when you go to `Run As...` you should now be able to see the maven options. Go to `Run As > Maven build...` and all you need to do is place the word *package* in the Goals field and you're ready to roll.

Comment: Thank you Martin, your solution is an option to build the project, but I want to know how I can display the menus and use them directly.

Comment: @Hocine I've added everything you should need to do from scratch to get up and running. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your project to a maven project if you haven't done yet by right clicking on your project in the Eclipse Project/Package explorer. Then follow:

```
Configure -> Convert to Maven Project
```

After that you can just right click again on the project `Run as` and you will see all Maven possibilities to execute your project build/install/clean etc.

Comment: In Configure there is only `Convert to plug-in project`.

Comment: Are you sure your `m2e-plugin` installation went well? In case it is not, try uninstalling and installing it once more, because if it is installed well then you should be seeing that `Configure Maven Project` or you can see `Maven Project` by new creation of a project. Can you go through `Windows -> Preferences` and see `Maven` in the list? If so, expand `Maven` option and check what is selected in `Installations`. I think yours should have `Embedded` installation option selected. But I recommend you install Maven separately (external) and that installation should the one to use.

Comment: I installed `maven` separately and I changed in `Window -> Preferences` the `Embedded` to the new maven version, but I get same thing when I select `Configure -> ...` only `Convert to plug-in project` found.

Comment: What is the Eclipse version are you using? Try creating a new project but choose Maven Project by selecting `Other` or `(CTRL+N)`, if you don't see `Maven Project` then the plugin isn't installed correctly. If that works try getting a new Eclipse installation.